# Why did Microsoft make Visual Studio Code with NodeJS and not .NET?

Tags: node.js, .net, web-applications, desktop-application

Trying to choose between NodeJS and .NET Core 3.0 for my next career stage and I can't find any information on why the most popular text editor, Visual Studio Code, is not made using Microsoft's own technologies.

What reasons were there for Microsoft to make an app in NodeJS instead of .NET?

Comment: I do not think that you will get a definitive answer for this one, since they(MS) surely considered many aspects. I suppose one of the bigger factors was, that the Monaco editor is written in JS and they probably wanted to keep the feel. So it makes sense to just write an Electron app and not try to integrate JS with some .NET

Comment: They do. Vscode written in typescript, 100% Microsoft product

Comment: @CfloweVisit typescript is javascript, not .NET C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that I'm giving a blind shot here, I'm not affiliated with Microsoft nor know their internal decisions.

There are several aspects to consider on why VSCode was written in NodeJS:

1. Widely adopted language: JavaScript is one of the most popular
   programming languages according to the latest StackOverflow survey,
   this results in more community support, which means that there are A
   LOT of commiters available to help developing the product and fixing
   problems. This also means that it's easier to develop extensions in
   a widely adopted language, this results in a larger ecosystem(Good
   for everyone!). The more popular the programming language, more
   people will be available to expanding the ecosystem and the product
   itself.
    Also developing in JavaScript is WAY more easy than .NET
   and also has a easier learning curve.
2. Electron: Electron is a Cross Platform Framework that is astonishingly easy to use. You can build an APP for every single platform with minimal effort. The reasoning behind this choice is quite obvious: Support as many platforms as possible with little effort.
   The wider the reach of the product, bigger the power, bigger adoption, bigger community.

As for your next career choice, you should consider analyzing your target market(Your city, if you wan't to stay there) and see what they are using.

Comment: .net jobs are everywhere but only in SME business. the big hitters in tech doing exciting stuff like Netflix Uber etc won't use .net. Personally I think NodeJS is the best way to go... especially as Microsoft have a habbit of messing with .Net and its very convoluted to achieve little